# Return initialisation of struct with union

Tags: c, struct, initialization, union

I'm trying to return a structure with the initialisation list syntax.

My structure is a bigger version of this:

```
typedef enum A {
  a,
  b,
} A;
    
typedef struct tagged_union {
  A tag;
  union {
    int a_value;
    float b_value;
  };
}tagged_union;
```

I have a function with this implementation:

```
tagged_union func() {
  return {a, 0};
}
```

but this send me the following error:

```
error: expected expression
  return {a, 0};
         ^
1 error generated.
```

The only solution i found is initializing in a variable to return:

```
tagged_union func() {
  tagged_union res = {a, 0};
  return res;
}
```

So my question is why isn't the first solution possible ? Is there any technical restriction that prevent it from being included in the C grammar?
I would like to know if there is other solution for packing the initialization with the return because in my case the tag are pretty numerous and doubling the code used for that seems tedious.

thanks in advance.

Comment: The short answer as to No. 1 is `return {a, 0};` is not a complete type. It is simply a brace-enclosed list of `a` and `0`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* include the initialization in the `return` statement but, to do so, you have to somehow convert it into a valid *expression*. Perhaps the simplest way to do this is to use a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

Leaving all other code unchanged, the following works (but with some warnings about not using braces for sub-objects):

```c
tagged_union func()
{
    return (tagged_union){ a, 0 };
}
```

Comment: thanks to both of you it's cleaner and i learned about compound literals so it's a win win.

Comment: @Saging You and I *both* learned about compound literals! :-)